# Hide a custom input element if category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the Custom Field Plugin to add a custom Field and call it to the content using `the_field();` in my `single.php`

I just  want to display this field on the all the categories except the "Articles which is 13", so I was trying somethin' like this:

```
<?php if !is_category( '13' ); { ?>
    <h3 class="single-product__price"><?php the_field('precio'); ?></h3>
<?php } ?>
```

But it is not working. I'm wondering how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `in_category`, and put the conditional statement in parentheses.

```
<?php if (!in_category( $cat )) { ?>
    <h3 class="single-product__price"><?php the_field('precio'); ?></h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Make sure `$cat` is [either ID (integer), name or slug (string)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Parameters) of the category.

Edit: I'm assuming you actually want to display the input on **posts** that are not in a particular category, hence [`in_category`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category). If you do indeed want to display it on all other **Category archive pages**, then [`is_category`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) would be correct.